# Correct use of flex. for a specific problem

Tags: css, html, javascript, flexbox

I am trying to create a page that displays dynamic content. I want to arrange my divs as so:

screen width <600px

```
    div1
div2    div3
  an-image
div4    div5
    div6
```

screen width >600px

```
       div1
div2   an-    div3
div4   img    div5
       div6
```

I have some experience using @media() to make content responsive, but I am not quite sure how to go about creating this particular arrangement of divs.

I would be greateful for any tips.

Comment: Am I able to edit it, or do I need to re-post it there?

Comment: You can flag it for a moderator (click the "flag" link under the question) and ask them to migrate it to StackOverflow... or copy it, delete it here, then post it at StackOverflow. You shouldn't post the same question at multiple Stack Exchange sites if it can be avoided.

Comment: This seems like a job for CSS grids: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout

Comment: You can use flex-wrap for that if you only want flex
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap
If the size of your main container change you can adapt the number of elements by line in function of the width.